# OpenCV: summed difference between frames with absdiff() - consecutive I-frame gives huge value spikes

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

**Problem description:**
Using OpenCV `absdiff(current_frame, previous_frame)` function and adding all values with `np.sum()`, I get unreasonably high sum values if `previous_frame` is a P-frame or B-frame and `current_frame` is an I-frame.
Function documentation: [cv2.absdiff()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga6fef31bc8c4071cbc114a758a2b79c14)

**Video source:**
Stream of home surveillance webcam, grabbed with ffmpeg. Cannot be shared due to sensitive information).
For reproducing problem: libx264 reencoded snippet of Big Buck Bunny with I-frame every 19th frame.
Download: https://www.mediafire.com/file/6vxxtjdafrxb0gc/bbb_gop_19.mp4/file

**Software and versions:**
Ubuntu 20.04  with ffprobe 4.2.4
conda, Python 3.9.6, OpenCV 4.5.2, matplotlib 3.4.2

**Python code for reproduction:**

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import subprocess

# Set video file name:
video_file = 'bbb_gop_19.mp4'

'''
ffrobe_output : string of frame types 
frame_types : single letter list of frame types
I_frames : List of I frames' indices
'''
try: 
    command = 'ffprobe -v error -show_entries frame=pict_type -of default=noprint_wrappers=1'.split()
    ffprobe_out = subprocess.check_output(command + [video_file]).decode()
    frame_types = ffprobe_out.replace('pict_type=','').split()
    I_frames = [int(frame[0]) for frame in zip(range(len(frame_types)), frame_types) if frame[1] == 'I']
except:
    raise ValueError("Could not call ffprobe to get I frames.")


'''Prepare list of sums of difference in two consecutive frames. '''
diff_list = []

'''
Open video file, read in first frame at position 0.
After successful read(), frame position property is set to 1.
Upon next call of read(), frame at position 1 will be read,
and frame position property will be set to 2.
'''
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
success, current_frame = cap.read()
current_frame = np.uint8(cv2.cvtColor(current_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)) # Convert RGB to gray scale
# DIAG:
# print("Next frame will be read at position:", cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)) 

while success == True:
    previous_frame = current_frame
    # DIAG: Print sum of all equal pixels: 360*640 = 230400
    # print(np.sum((previous_frame == current_frame))) 
    # DIAG:
    # print("Next frame will be read at position:", cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
    try:
        success, current_frame = cap.read()
        # DIAG:
        # print("Successfully read frame at position:", cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)-1)
        current_frame = np.uint8(cv2.cvtColor(current_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
    except:
        # DIAG:
        # print("No more frames can be read, aborting while-loop.")
        break
    
    # DIAG: Print sum of all equal pixels: 360*640 = 230400
    # print(np.sum((previous_frame == current_frame))) 
    
    # Calculate difference matrix between current frame and previous frame
    differences = cv2.absdiff(current_frame, previous_frame)
    # Sum up all elements in the difference matrix, append sum to list.
    diff_list.append(np.sum(differences)) 


# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

plt.plot(diff_list[:], label=str('Sum of pixel diff. betw.\n' 'frame (1-0) to (299-298)' + '\npeak to peak:'  + str(np.ptp(diff_list[:]))))
plt.plot(diff_list[0:18], label=str('Sum of pixel diff. betw.\n' 'frame (1-0) to (19-18)' + '\npeak to peak:'  + str(np.ptp(diff_list[0:18]))))
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Plot will give:
[image: Plot of summed differences between frames]

**Question:**

1. There is no visible change in the video that would explain the huge spikes.  How can these be avoided?
2. In case of any logic errors in my code that would lead to the spikes, please indicate.
3. How can I continuously quantify the change in two consecutive frames without having to eliminate the spikes (the ultimate goal is to quantify change in ROIs)?

Thank you.

Comment: to be expected. one cause: with long GOPs error accumulates, hence the output drifts away from the input ("jerking" effect). another cause: I-frames may get fewer bits than they'd need, so they get murdered with artefacts, which the P/B-frames gradually fix up... until the next I-frame ("pumping" effect). "no visible change" because your eyes are merely human, computers see every tiny difference.

Comment: Thank you @ChristophRackwitz for the explanation. I extended my question part. What would be the correct way to continuously get the difference between two frames (to quantify change in ROIs)?

Comment: you want "change detection", eh? browse https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html because simple sum of absolute differences gives proportional weight to deviations... when you might want to completely ignore small changes (noise). those background subtractors do even better because they aren't trivial.